# How do I get self host to work with IoC for Web-Api integration tests?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-web-api, autofac, self-hosting

I've taken [hints from here](http://cromwellhaus.com/2012/02/asp-net-web-api-integration-tests-with-self-hosting/) to come up with this integration test for my new Web Api project. I'm trying to build a rest web service and I have a helper client that I plan to release to API consumers. That's the `ExampleClientHelper` type there. Oh and btw, this all wires up to the `ValuesController` that's provided with the project template for a MVC4 Web Api Visual Studio project - I'm keeping things simple while I nut this out.

`ExampleClientHelper` replaces all the request/response in the aforementioned reference example. It's using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) internally.

```
[Test]
[Ignore]
public void ValuesHelper_ShouldReturn_value1_And_value2_AsTypedObject()
{
    // IoC prep
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var container = builder.Build();

    // web server prep
    var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
    var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseUri);
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // yes, the routing needs to be copied over. it's not compatible with the MVC routes
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Api", "api/{controller}/{id}",
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, namespaces = new[] { typeof(ValuesController).Namespace } });

    // start the server and make a request
    new HttpSelfHostServer(config)
        .OpenAsync()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var client = new ExampleClientHelper(baseUri);
                var values = client.GetValues();

                // then test the response
                Assert.AreEqual("value1", values.ElementAt(0));
                Assert.AreEqual("value2", values.ElementAt(1));
            })
        .Wait();
}
```

The code above works fine as long as you don't modify `ValuesController`. ie. it remains having an implicit parameterless constructor.

The problem I'm having is that the self host server can't seem to instantiate my `ValuesController` when I modify it to require a dependency. The issue is, I get the same exception from the response from my helper client whether I wire up the [Autofac DependencyResolver](http://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi) or not. This is what is returned in the Content of the response, nicely formatted as JSON thanks to RestSharp:

> {"ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","Message":"Type 'Embed.ECSApi.RestServer.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor","StackTrace":"   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"}

So clearly the self host server is trying to create `ValuesController` but it can't. Why? I thought I wired up the DependencyResolver properly. I'm expecting to get an Autofac exception instead which complains about my dependency that I haven't configured.

Comment: on a side note, you shouldn't do integration tests with self host. Use in-memory host for that. This way you are not dependant on the test machine, its port availability etc anymore. http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/

Comment: HI Filip. Is [this the same thing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers)? I agree generally however I want these integration tests to also test my helper and my helper makes a real http request. I also see more value from an integration test that acts as a real server rather than "most" of a real server (which is what it seems the in-memory method is doing). Different use case I guess.

Comment: It's the same thing in a sense that HttpServer simply derives from HttpMessageHandler. There is a great post about that http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/asp-net-web-api-in-memory-hosting/. This is the so called "russian doll" model where you get to chain infinite amount of message handlers in a perfect cleint-server symmetry. In memory host does everything the same as web- or self- host, except it doesn't cannibalize the port and cannot be accessed from outside of your machine. It doesn't pretend to be a server, it is one. Of course as you said - there are valid use cases for everything

Comment: Surely you can't call it a server when it does not accept HTTP packet requests, right?

Comment: @FilipW I use the in-memory approach now. :D Thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to register the controller with the container and Web API is trying to create the instance for you.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register API controllers using assembly scanning.
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(ValuesController).Assembly);

var container = builder.Build();
```

You can also register the individual controller if required.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. I just updated your answer so it worked with the particular case in my example - my tests were in a separate assembly so `RegisterApiControllers` required the assembly of my controllers.